# Network checking in android

Tags: android

I want to check the network connectivity in android application.so i inserted the following code

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
     Context context = getApplicationContext();
     ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) 
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

      NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
      if (info != null)
      {
       for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
       {
        if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) 
        {
         return true;
        }
       }
      }

     return false;
    }
```

when i removed network cable in my computer the program crashed.but when i disable Airplane Mode in Emulator,it correctly shows "NETWORK NOT AVAILABLE".
How to we actually check?

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace produced when your "program crashed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try it on actual device.

My inference from your post is, you are trying on an emulator.
And I think emulator is linked to the network interface of the system
Hence it could have failed.

Other change what I propose :
`NetworkInfo info = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();

if (info.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED )

    return true`